# Custom User Model versus Django User Model

Tags: python, django, backend

I am making a web application using Django as my backend, and I was wondering what the best practice is when dealing with models representing user account information (username, password, email, etc.). I am aware of an existing [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) model, as well as the practice of [creating a custom user model](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model) by subclassing `AbstractUser`. However, I am confused as to how this is any different than subclassing `models.Model` and creating my own user model from scratch.

Does anyone have advice as to what is best practice in this situation?

Comment: In general when beginning a new project one should always use a custom user model, even if it only extends `AbstractUser` and has nothing new. This makes it easy if later on some new requirements come up which cause us to need a custom user model.

Comment: One can of course simply subclass `models.Model` but that means one has to remember to include all things Django is expecting from a user model. In general if one wants to customize much more than normal they would subclass `AbstractBaseUser` instead of `AbstractUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [Django User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/) has particular fields and if it enough for you use it. If you want to add new fields or change something that you can create new model. If you override User model good practice to [define it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/) via `User = get_user_model()`.